# Loading multiple Base64 img in HTML file

Tags: html, browser, base64

I want to know if using multiple times the same base64 img will be :

- loaded once by the browser and it will re-use the string? (more performance)
- or loaded every time it encounters the base64 string? (meaning I should use a standard img format like SVG/png/jpeg that will be loaded only once)

Note : I can't use CSS to use the base64 img in a class in this case! I use a HTML file. I have inserted MOD Deflate / Gzip into the .htaccess, maybe this will make the string loaded only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an uncompressed HTML file with multiple `IMG` elements hard-coded with the same base64 encoded `src` attribute then those bytes for the base64 data will be transmitted mutiple times across the the connection.

If you apply a compression algorithm to the HTML file before it is transmitted then the compression algorithm will likely notice the duplication and account for it, reducing the payload.

If you know ahead of time which images are duplicated then you could set the `IMG` src attributes using JavaSript. This would mean the data is only transmitted once - though in my instance you have the overhead of jQuery. e.g.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script 
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(load_images);

        function load_images() {
            $(".base64_image").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,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");
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img class="base64_image" />
    <img class="base64_image" />
    <img class="base64_image" />
</body>

</html>
```